# Laplace transform in a block system

Tags: control, control-system, homework, laplace-transform, block-diagram

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to understand the resolution of the problem 5.11, but I can't understand how she gets the expression in the rectangle:
$$\dot{x}_1=-x_1+2u$$
How can I get the expression in the rectangle?

Comment: I don't understand why someone would write the small case s so confusingly then almost do the same when writing an x.

Answer (score 1):

\$ u \$ is the input signal it might be a real number so \$ \dot{u}=0 \$

so i would expect the result to be : \$ \dot{x}_1=−x_1+3u \$

Comment: Why did she obtain two different expressions for $\dot{x_1}$? What is the correct expression?

Comment: Which one is correct? That’s a good question! If you can post the rest of the exercise it might be helpful.

Comment: I put the rest of the resolution in the post. I don't understand why she gets two expressions for $\dot{x_1}$.

Comment: You have to replace x1 by w1 with the given assimilation that  w1=x1+u
Then you have (x1+u) *(s+1) =(s+3) *u
Finally, this the result you are expecting.